# Telephony.SECRET_CODE and all Samsung devices

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I want to implement a debug activity that will be lauched after when we enter a code in phone dialer. I want to use custome SECRET_CODE.

My android manifest look like this:

```
 <receiver android:name="com.madme.mobile.sdk.broadcast.SecretReceiver" >
  <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE" />
     <data android:host="666" android:scheme="android_secret_code" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Sombody can help me with this? Evry single mobile is working (even some cheap phones) only samsung is my pain. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Try using this Samsung permissions in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.sec.factory.permission.KEYSTRING"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.sec.testingsettings.permission.KEYSTRING"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.app.servicemodeapp.permission.KEYSTRING"/>
```

Comment: I'v tried. And tried many Samsung phones and this just not working for samsung phones.

Comment: Try downloading this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.simon.marquis.secretcodes&hl=es_419). Check that you're not using a secret code that is already taken. And also check if you can execute another apps secret codes.

Comment: I'v tried apps like this. On some devices you can see all secret codes but not all of theme will work.